# Zip deployment failed when doing `az webapp up`

Tags: azure, f#, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

I have an F# solution. There're a bunch of projects (Class Libraries) and my ASP.NET Core project. Lets name it `Web` I have `wwwroot` folder with some html files. I'm trying to run `az webapp up --sku F1 --name MGMYGL --os-type windows --html`(like decribed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?tabs=net70&pivots=development-environment-cli)) in a Web folder but I get an exception:

`Zip deployment failed. {'id': '11aeb1b3f27148c4929710f61766b970', 'status': 3, 'status_text': '', 'author_email': 'N/A', 'author': 'N/A', 'deployer': 'ZipDeploy', 'message': 'Created via a push deployment', 'progress': '', 'received_time': '2023-11-12T08:22:55.2894544Z', 'start_time': '2023-11-12T08:22:55.4144803Z', 'end_time': '2023-11-12T08:22:55.5707154Z', 'last_success_end_time': None, 'complete': True, 'active': False, 'is_temp': False, 'is_readonly': True, 'url': 'https://mgmygl.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest', 'log_url': 'https://mgmygl.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log', 'site_name': 'MGMYGL', 'provisioningState': 'Failed'}. Please run the command az webapp log deployment show -n MGMYGL -g michaelsamoilenkood_rg_6488`

If I run related command to get logs, I can see this:
`[{"log_time":"2023-11-12T08:22:55.5550707Z","id":"","message":"'C:\\local\\Temp\\zipdeploy\\extracted\\Web.fsproj' is not a deployable project.","type":2,"details_url":null}]`

If I change the root directory to `wwwroot` folder and execute deploy command again - it'll deploy succesfully but as expected with .dotnet dlls:) Another interesting thing is if I use my builtin IDEs way of publising azure apps (I'm using Rider), everything will work.
But I would like to use console, it's important in my case and for my purposes

Comment: I can follow the doc you shared to deploy the ASP.NET web app successfully with a c# project.  By the way, are you using azure DevOps during the deployment? If not, you may replace the azure devops tag with F# tag.

Comment: @MiaoTian-MSFT but were you able to open the website that azure created for it? because I repeated that steps for dummy project as well and I finished with `503 Service Unavailable` when I was opening the related website.
Yes, you're right, it's not related to azure devopes so I replaced that tag with F# tag

Comment: Can you try deploying with `az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group <rgname> --name <webapp_name> --src <projectname.zip>`

Comment: @PravallikaKV, the problem is that I can't do like you said. My `Web` project has `wwwroot` folder and when I'm building everything to release, that folder isn't being included (which kinda makes sense). So then when I'll execute your command, `wwwroot` hmtl files won't be published and that means that my app won't have any UI part :). Somehow when I do publish via Rider it's able to group everything correctly and then I have everything needed (`wwwroot` and F# binaries). So that means it's possible somehow to publish everything without changing any configurations, etc..